# Android 11. socketOutStream.close() closes SSLSocket

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, socket.io, outputstream

When I use this code on the `Android 11`

```
  OutputStream socketOutStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
            socketOutStream.write(bb.array());
            socketOutStream.write(data);
            socketOutStream.flush();
            socketOutStream.close();
```

`socketOutStream.close()` closes `SSLSocket` and when I call `mSocket.getInputStream()` I get `java.net.SocketException: socket closed`.

If I use this code on the Android 10 and below, then there is no problem.

Why it happens?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I suspect it's something to do with this change: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-all#ssl-sockets-conscrypt

I am experiencing something similar, where a connection times out before the server response is read. Only happens on Android 11+.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty normal that closing a stream closes the socket too.

Not only on Android 11.

Comment: Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream

Comment: system resources associated with this stream == SSLSocket?!

Comment: There was no problem on the Android <11. It is a fact!

Comment: Can be. But there are more things on Android 11 that follow the lines better. Why are you surprised? And what is the problem exactly? I never close streams when using a socket. Join me!

Comment: I'm surprised that this code worked correctly for 5 years and more than on 10000 devices.))